# T-SQL date conversion dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, type-conversion

I've read a couple of posts on converting from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd but the code is not working (CONVERT AND CAST). Please see example below and kindly advise if you can help as the error I'm getting is 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string'. If I change my date_engaged to '2010-09-12' it will work but I need to convert it somehow because if i say select getdate(), it will spit out this date format (yyyy-mm-dd).

It's interesting because the code is not working for me on my work PC and I'm using Microsoft SQL server Management studio 2008, but at home, it works perfectly fine.

```
    create table test(
name varchar (10),
date_engaged nvarchar (20),
timestamp2 nvarchar (20),
LOS nvarchar (20)
)

insert into test (name,date_engaged) values ('JJ','12/09/2010')

update test
set timestamp2=CAST(DATEADD(month,0,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,getdate()),-1)) AS DATE)

update test
set LOS=DATEDIFF(day,date_engaged,timestamp2)/365.25
```

thx

Comment: Is there a reason you can't convert it at the application level?

Comment: It's because you didn't state the date format. And each computer probably has different versions or setups for the implicit data type conversion.  And why aren't you using date data type for date ?

Comment: As others have commented before: use DATE type to store dates. If it is not possible to change the underlying data type: convert the VARCHAR first to DATE, then convert the DATE back to a VARCHAR with the appropriate format. This link shows the [options for CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Comment: Hi, I was expecting this response. :)   ok, but even if I put date for date_engaged and date for timestamp2, it still doesn't work because when you say insert into test values ('12/09/2010' is not in the format it wants it to be. so that's my problem.

Comment: @user3497385 that's because you are *still* using strings, with an ambiguous format too. The best option is to use a parameterized query and pass the date from the client as a date parameter. Or use an unambiguous format like `20100912` to store Sep 12, 2010, or the ISO 8601 datetime format. Even `2010-09-12` is *not* unambiguous for date-only literals.

Comment: BTW dates do not have *any* format, they are binary values. The way SSMS displays a date value has *nothing* to do with how the value is stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a look at the [MSDN docs for CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(SQL.80).aspx) where you will find that we need to provide the format also so that it can format the date as per our reruirement. The reason why it is working on your home system, is may be because your system is configured in the format in which you are giving the dates.

A fix to your problem

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(13) = '12/09/2010'

SELECT RIGHT(@x,4) + '-' + LEFT(RIGHT(@x,7),2) + '-' + LEFT(@x,2)
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2792/2)**

**On a side note:**

It is not recommended to use `NVARCHAR` or `VARCHAR` or `CHAR` to store dates, so as to avoid these types of issues. You can better use `DATE` datatype to store dates.

Comment: there is probably a reason why its stored as nvarchar, so theres no point in pointing the obvious out

Comment: @theweeknd:- That is the reason why it is sentenced as `On a side note` ;)

Comment: So even if you do this, the problem remains: create table test (
name varchar (50),
timestamp2 date,
date_engaged date,
LOS nvarchar (60)
)


insert into test (name,date_engaged) values ('jj','25/09/2005')

Comment: My concern with the declare option is it refers to a specific date(?). I have thousands of rows with different dates.

Comment: @user3497385:- So in case your `@x` you can use the name of your dateColumn which probably is `date_engaged`. And in that case you dont have to declare it.

Comment: aha! :-)  Thank you :)